# Certbot - не работает сертификат для поддомена

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, certbot

Установил certbot на ubuntu 18

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Далее все автоматически усталовилось и я получил сообщение, что все ок.
Но в браузере красный замок - браузер не доверяет сертификату.

Домен на сервере - субдомен demo.example.com

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Что `certbot` написал вам в конфиг `nginx`? там должно быть что-то вроде `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot`. Что выдаёт команда `openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.example.com/fullchain.pem -text -noout` (подставьте правильный путь к сертификату)? Что пишет браузер про сертификат - неверный срок действия, недействительный корневой сертификат, что-то ещё? Без описания симптомов трудно поставить диагноз ))

Comment: на команду openssl открывает BEGIN CERTIFICATE и строки сертификата. listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/demo.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

Comment: браузер просто выдает что подключение не защищено

Comment: Антон, добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о сертификате, загруженном certbot-ом в ваш вопрос.

Comment: Certbot выдал два пути на fullchain.pem и privkey.pm. Какую именно информацию?

Comment: Все браузеры помимо "сообщение не защищено" выдают дополнительную диагностику. Например, если корневой сертификат не является доверенным, Хром пишет NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, Мозилла (кнопка Дополнительно) SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER, Интернет эксплорер (кнопка Подробнее) DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104188/discussion-between-pak-uula-and-anton-bogomolov).

Answer (score 0):

Certbot требует указания фактического нахождения сайта (папки). То есть для поддомена, если он в другой папке, нужны другие сертификаты.

Comment: это ответ от бота, среагировавшего на ключевые слова («certbot», «поддомен»)? потому как ответ прекрасный, но это ответ на совсем другой вопрос. а у автора вопроса банально нифига не настроено, но он почему-то ожидал, что установка пакета сделает всё за него.